# Copy Files to a Location Identified by a Registry Key

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I want to write a small little application that will copy some embedded files to a location identified within a registry key.

I want the application to look for that key, and if it finds it, copy the files.  Otherwise tell the user that they must perform some other action first.

But I have no idea how to access a Registry Key from C#. Any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For registry queries / manipulation you can use the [**Registry**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: Stupid .NET and its non-intuitive class names! :)

Comment: @aquinas Heh, yeah.  Drives me nuts :)